# how to capture a video frame from a video file

Tags: c#, asp.net

any one can help me with a c# code to grab frames from a video file,

I am working on a live streaming server on (Asp.Net & c#)..
so when a user uploads his files after live streaming, at the point I have to capture a video frame, so that it can be listed 
in the format of a you-tube video list...

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/samples/video.html) - it is a mature set of libraries for processing images and video.

Answer (score 1):

You should be try this it works nice:

```
private Capture capture = null;

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if ( capture == null )
                    throw new ApplicationException( "Please select a video and/or audio device." );
                if ( !capture.Cued )
                    capture.Filename = txtFilename.Text;
                capture.Start();
                btnCue.Enabled = false;
                btnStart.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show( ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.ToString() );
            }
        }
```